# ajaxButton not working when using Lift Wiring

Tags: scala, lift

My goal is to have text displayed normally on initial load, but when an 'Edit' button is pressed, the text changes to be an input text box.  The html is this:

```
<div class="user">
    <div>
        <span>Edit</span><lift:WiredUser.edit />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <lift:WiredUser.email />
    </div>
</div>
```

My wiring class looks like so:

```
class WiredUser {

  val userToWire = (Users.userForDisplay or userDetail.currentValue).get

  private object User {
    val entity = ValueCell(userToWire)
    val edit = ValueCell(false)
    val email = edit.lift(b => entity.lift(_.getEmail.asScala.headOption).get)
  }

  def edit = {
    WiringUI.toNode(User.edit, JqWiringSupport.fade)((mode: Boolean, ns:NodeSeq) => { Wired.editable(
      mode,
      mode,
      (b: Boolean) => ajaxButton(h("Done"), () => {User.edit.set(false); JsCmds.Noop}),
      (b: Boolean) => ajaxButton(h("Edit"),  () => {User.edit.set(true); JsCmds.Noop})
    )})
  }

  def email = WiringUI.toNode(User.email, JqWiringSupport.fade)((email: Option[String], ns: NodeSeq) => {
    Wired.editable(
      email.getOrElse(""),
      User.edit.get,
      (n: String) => ajaxText(n, s => {refresh(setEmail(_, s)); JsCmds.Noop}),
      (n: String) => h(n)
    )
  })
}

object Wired {

   def editable[T](o: T, mode: Boolean, t: (T)=> NodeSeq, f: (T) => NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {
     mode match {
       case true => t(o)
       case false => f(o)
     }
   }
}
```

On initial load, there is an 'Edit' button that is displayed.  When that button is pressed, an ajax call with the form data "F531904251245BAWYT:true" is executed, however the function attached to the ajax call is never executed: () => {User.edit.set(true); JsCmds.Noop} and the result is empty:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
});
```

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Note that I have submitted this to the Lift google group without a response.

I have created a working example:
https://github.com/OleTraveler/scala-wiring-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced with the same problem and I've found some solution. I created my custom version of net.liftweb.WiringUI (MyWiringUI), where I changed the following methods

```
  def toNode[T](in: NodeSeq, cell: Cell[T], jsEffect: (String, Boolean, JsCmd) => JsCmd)(f: (T, NodeSeq) => NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
val myElem: Elem = in.find {
  case e: Elem => true
  case _ => false
}.map(_.asInstanceOf[Elem]).getOrElse(<span id={Helpers.nextFuncName}>{in}</span>)

val (elem: Elem, id: String) = Helpers.findOrAddId(myElem)
addJsFunc(cell, (t: T, first: Boolean) => {
  jsEffect(id, first, SetHtml(id, f(t, elem.child)))
})
f(cell.currentValue._1, elem)
```

}

and

```
  def addJsFunc[T](cell: Cell[T], f: (T, Boolean) => JsCmd) {
for {
  cometActor <- S.currentCometActor
} cell.addDependent(cometActor)

val trc = TransientRequestCell(cell)
var lastTime: Long = 0L
var lastValue: T = null.asInstanceOf[T]
for {
  sess <- S.session
} sess.addPostPageJavaScript(() => {
  val (value, ct) = trc.get
  val first = lastTime == 0L
  if (first || (ct > lastTime && value != lastValue)) {
    lastValue = value
    lastTime = ct
    if(first) Noop
    else f(value, first)
  }else{
    Noop
  }
})
```

}

The most important change is:

```
        if(first) Noop
    else f(value, first)
```

Thats all.

Whole example you can find at here https://github.com/mmigacz/lift_wiring

Some additional information about my problem you can find on lift forum https://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/932ce4d45ccd6582?hl=pl

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I've moved to a different feature for now so it'll be a couple of weeks before I can test this out.